# I can't understand this expression and what composition has phrase "execution time binding"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Virtual address: logical address in execution time binding which is different from the
>   respective physical address

Is *execution time binding* an adjective clause?

Or where should I put comma? for example can I put comma before *which*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Execution time binding" could be made less ambiguous by hyphenating the first two words: "execution-time binding".  Neither of these is an adjective clause, but "*in* execution time binding" is a prepositional phrase acting as an adjective.

You may insert a comma before "which", but you are not required to do so, especially in what appears to be the context of a glossary, which is written in terse sentence-fragments rather than long, complex sentences.  There is nowhere else in the expression where a comma would fit.

The whole phrase means that a virtual address is a logical address, as bound at execution time, and is not the same as the "real" physical address to which it refers.